# Completed 302 Found in Rails 3 Registration Process only on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, http-status-code-302

In my Rails 3 app, for some reason I'm getting a 302 in my registration process. Specifically, when I redirect from creating a new User to editing their Profile I get redirected out of the app to `/login`. This only happens on Heroku. If I run the app locally, it works as it should.

Here's my `heroku logs`:

```
2012-02-10T02:22:05+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 98.218.231.113 at     2012-02-10 02:22:05 +0000
2012-02-10T02:22:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-10T02:22:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Saving attachments.
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered user_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb (0.4ms)
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 964ms
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to andy@dundermifflin.com (694ms)
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 heroku[router]: POST myapp.org/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=984ms status=302 bytes=97
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://myapp.org/signup/join
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4PjdAx5aaSph3KBDQfiPlJTlvTsh+DDTF1x+S7Ol2jc=", "user"=>{"profile_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"Andrew", "last_name"=>"Bernard", "bio"=>""}, "email"=>"andy@dundermifflin.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up For myapp"}
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered user_mailer/registration_confirmation.html.erb (0.6ms)
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 98.218.231.113 - - [10/Feb/    2012:02:22:06 +0000] "POST /users HTTP/1.1" 302 97 "http://myapp.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10" myapp.org
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signup/join" for 98.218.231.113 at     2012-02-10 02:22:06 +0000
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.org/signup/join dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=29ms status=302 bytes=91
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by ProfilesController#edit as HTML
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://myapp.org/login
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 12ms
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 98.218.231.113 - - [10/Feb/    2012:02:22:06 +0000] "GET /signup/join HTTP/1.1" 302 91 "http://myapp.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10" myapp.org
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/login" for 98.218.231.113 at     2012-02-10 02:22:06 +0000
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
2012-02-10T02:22:06+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.org/login dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=27ms status=200 bytes=3062
```

In my `users_controller.rb`:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to join_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

In my `routes.rb`:

```
match "/signup/join" => "profiles#edit", :as => 'join'
```

So if I look at my logs, I'm submitting a `POST` to `/users`, sending an email, and redirecting to the `edit` action in `profiles_controller.rb`. So it seems like everything should be correct but I'm getting redirected. Has anyone had this happen to them too?

**UPDATE:** In my `profiles_controller.rb`:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit, :update]
  layout "application", :except => [:edit, :show]

  def user
    @user = current_user
  end

  def edit
    @profile = user.profile
    render :layout => "join_form"
  end
```

In my `sessions_controller.rb`:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController  
  def new
  end

  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:email].downcase, params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      if user.profile.higher_ed?
        redirect_to user.profile, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
      else
        redirect_to join_path, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
      end
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password. Try again!"
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

My `gemfile`:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "aws-s3", :require => "aws/s3"
gem "aws-sdk"
gem "cancan"
gem "cocaine"
gem "fastercsv"
gem "nifty-generators"
gem "jquery-rails", ">= 1.0.12"
gem "paperclip"
gem "rails", "3.0.5"
gem "rake", "0.9.2"
gem "ransack"
gem "twitter"
gem "mocha", :group => :test
group :production, :development, :test do
  gem "pg"
end
gem "pg"
```

Comment: what does your `profiles#edit` action do? maybe you have some before-filter or something like this that is doing the redirect?

Comment: Just added my `profiles#edit` action as an update. I've also added my `sessions_controller`. Sorry for not including that before. This was working before but I've made so many changes I'm not sure where this could have gone wrong.

Comment: i guess that `before_filter :authenticate` or any other before-filter is causing you trouble.

Comment: But if that was the case wouldn't it cause the same redirect when the app is running locally? I only have the problem when the app is on Heroku.

Comment: probably yes, but i guess that something is just messed up, so how are you going to solve it without having a look at everything that is interfering with your normal controller workflow?

Comment: Yeah, true. I guess that's the best way then? As opposed to trying a test...

Comment: I started removing some stuff in Profiles#edit and I got a nomethod error. I'll post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @phoet suggested above, I started removing code that was potentially causing issues and I got a no method error, which led me to my solution. I had to rework the logic in my `current_user` method. I changed it from:

```
def current_user
  return unless session[:user_id]
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
end
```

To:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= lookup_user
end

def lookup_user
  if cookies[:auth_token]
    User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token])
  elsif session[:user_id]
    User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this 302 found issues, see how it get resolved-

In my case i was accessing method across the controller using AJAX call, another controller i have added authorize_resource as devise method to authenticate request.

Then I skipped particular method skip_authorize_resource :only => :name_of_method(Action).

It solve the issue.

Thanks.